# Can Microsoft Project 2016 work with MSPS 2013

Tags: project, ms-project

We have some windows issues with Microsoft project 2013. It will not connect with msps 2013. We were forced to update windows to the latest version. We are wondering if it would be better to get MS Project 2016 so we can interact with our MSPS 2013 on prem. We know MS Project 2016 works well with current version of Windows 10. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

After research I have discovered that MS project installed with the correct suite will connect to MSPS 2013 on the server. It is backwards compatible and has no issues with current release of Windows (1909).